# Trying to access s3 Bucket Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 169.254.169.254:80 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1133:16)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

After sending an image to be uploaded to the s3 bucket, i get this error "Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 169.254.169.254:80 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1133:16)". Was before getting a credential error, then I changed something and this began popping up. I also created a new project with same exact code and was receiving the same error as above.

```
//s3-upload.js
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
const uuid = require('uuid').v4;
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const s3 = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });
// Needs AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

const upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3,
        bucket: 'sample-test-pdf-upload',
        metadata: (req, file, cb) => {
            cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname });
        },
        key: (req, file, cb) => {
            const ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
            cb(null, `${uuid()}${ext}`);
        }
    })
});

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.post('/upload', upload.array('avatar'), (req, res) => {
    return res.json({ status: 'OK', uploaded: req.files.length });
});

app.listen(5050, () => console.log('App is listening...'))

//server-upload.js
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const uuid = require('uuid').v4;
const app = express();
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'uploads')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const { originalname } = file;
        // or 
        // uuid, or fieldname
        cb(null, originalname);
    }
})
const upload = multer({ storage }); // or simply { dest: 'uploads/' }
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.post('/upload', upload.array('avatar'), (req, res) => {
    return res.json({ status: 'OK', uploaded: req.files.length });
});

app.listen(5050, () => console.log('App is listening...'))


//index.html
<h1>File Upload</h1>

<form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="avatar">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you checked the S3 endpoint?

Comment: Where are you running this code? Is it on an Amazon EC2 instance? Does it have an IAM Role assigned to the instance? The reference to `169.254.169.254:80` suggests that it is having problems accessing the EC2 metadata service.

Comment: I am using the Amazon S3. I do have an IAM role running. When I hard coded in the terminal the region of the s3 bucket that's when the error began popping up. Im running the code in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: i get same error, did you manage to find solution?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen with [multer-s3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3), when AWS credentials are not properly configured. eg, you're trying to use environment variables, but there's a typo in them, or they're not getting pulled in properly.

AWS will first looks for environment variables, then for a `~/.aws/credentials` file. If that fails, it will try accessing [the EC2 metadata service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html) -- as if you were running this code in a EC2 server, with an IAM role.

But you're not running on an EC2 instance (I assume), so there is no metadata service, and you get a network error.

In short, [**double check your AWS credentials configuration**.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html)